# How to bulk add 200 pages to Google Analytics segment

Tags: google-analytics

We have a site where most pages are in the root domain with no subdirectories i.e. example.com/URL

We want to analyse our blog activity within Google Analytics by segment but all the blog posts are also on the root domain i.e. there is no example.com/blog/ subdirectory.

Is there a way to bulk segment pages within Google Analytics? I want to avoid creating a segment manually that contains 200 blog posts. I have a list of the 200 urls we want in this segment.

Answer (score 0):

If you have not implemented a content grouping or information in custom dimension that can identify those pages, Google Analytics cannot know it alone. If you haven't, you need to create a regex based on the URL.

Answer (score 0):

What I understand from your question is that URL is not changing on changing the pages. If this is the case then you have to apply listeners inside code to identify when the page is changing and on the page change events you have to fire GA pageview calls manually with correct page view information.